# PHP end tag is showing

Tags: php, html

When i open this page (processorder.php) in Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m I get this bit: 
'Order processed'; ?>"

in html instead of "Order processed". Why is this and how can I Fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bob's Auto parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>
<?php
echo <p>'Order processed'</p>;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The other case when the end tag shows, is when one puts PHP code into a `somename.html` file. It works fine only when the file is renamed to `somename.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use html tag inside the quotes

```
<?php
echo '<p>Order processed</p>';
?>
```

**processorder.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bob's Auto parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>
<?php echo '<p>Order processed</p>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where you are running this?

Comment: I'm running this on Windows 8.1, XAMPP v3.2.1

Comment: I mean in php server or outside ?

Comment: The files are stored inside xampp/htdocs/. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: yes, are you sure you have provided complete code? check with the edited content in answer and run your page as http://localhost/processorder.php

Comment: There was an error in my path, your answer is correct, thanks.